# How to mount mtp devices to the same location?

Tags: linux-mint, mount, mtp

Android phone mounts to different locations each time it is plugged in. It is annoying to have to change the location each time I want to sync docs between computer and phone.

Is it possible to always mount to the same location? In Windows 10, it mounts to the same point (something like `mtp:/phone_name`). But with Linux Mint, it mounts to `mtp://[usb:002,006]/` and the numbers change each time...

Comment: The numbers correspond to the USB port the device is connected to, assuming you plug it in in exactly the same port with the exact same sequence of hubs (including the port the hubs are connected to), you _should_ get the same numbers.  Unfortunately, Linux doesn't have 100% stable enumeration of USB devices (what's plugged in at boot can change how things get enumerated), so that may only give you the same numbers for a given boot of the system.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn If I simply unplug and plug in again immediately, it increments the device (2nd number) but the bus number (1st number) remains the same. I assume this means that I can't get Linux Mint to assign the same numbers each time?

Comment: That sounds like something isn't realizing that the device is being disconnected, and is still trying to use it.  You can get similar behavior sometimes when a hard disk that's in use disconnects for a short time (the original device node will remain visible until everything closes it).